# Dictionary reference keeps throwing an unsolved reference

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am building a mock terminal-like program using python, and am trying to build a login system for it.

My directory setup, after going through multiple revisions, eventually came out to look like this:

```py
pythonapp-harlker/
    __init__.py
    loginCheck.py
    main.py
    userlist.py
```

`__init__.py` is empty, and `main.py`'s main code chunk looks like this:

```py
from loginCheck import *
loginFunc = Login()

loginFunc.login()
if loginFunc.login().checkPass == True:
    print("Welcome %s!" % (username))
```

Importing `loginCheck` returns no error, so naturally, I looked at `loginCheck.py`.

```py
import sys, platform, importlib

import hashlib
from userlist import *

class Login:
    def login(self):
        username = input("Username: ")
        password = input("Password: ")
        password = str.encode(password)
        password = str(hashlib.md5(password).hexdigest())
        if username in users:
            userPassAndIndex = users.get(username)
            if password == userPassAndIndex[0]:
                checkPass = True
                value = userPassAndIndex[1]
            else:
                self.login()
        else:
            self.login()
```

Looking at a debugger, it keeps telling me that `loginCheck.py` is unable to import a dictionary from `userlist.py`.

`userlist.py`

```py
users = {
    'localAdmin10': ["086e717a4524329da24ab80e0a9255e2", 0],
    'orlovm': ["505ec2b430fa182974ae44ede95ca180", 1],
    'testUser10': ["90e611f269e75ec5c86694f900e7c594", 2],
    'torradiRemote': ["0b841ebf6393adac25950a215aecc3d1", 3],
}
```

Additionally, while running the python code (from `main.py`), the code seems unable to detect if the input username and passwords are correct.

I've looked at tons of stackOverflow pages and external sources but I'm at a kind of "programmer's block" now.

Comment: Have you tried using a relative import? `from .userlist import *` (add a leading dot)

Comment: @BUZZY When I try to do that, it throws a  `cannot import name 'userlist' from '__main__'`

Comment: There are quite a few problems with this code, even once you've fixed the import issue.

Comment: @DanielRoseman damn really? I need to work on my python-fu then.

Comment: Which file did you execute to check if that worked? Where did you run it from (what's the path)?

Comment: @BUZZY when I run it from loginCheck, it throws that error when I replace the code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code runs fine on Python 3+, and breaks on Python 2.7, let me explain why:

- the input function you want to use with Python 2.7 is `raw_input`, not `input`. The `input` function in Python 2.7, evaluates the user input as a Python expression, so in your case, can't find it and send an exception
- `raw_input` was renamed `input` starting Python 3.0

So to sum it up, you just have to pick the right function depending on which version of Python you'd like to use. `raw_input`for Python 2.7, `input` for Python 3.